# How to display the definition of a function

Tags: julia

This is probably a newbie question... but is it possible to show the definition of a (user defined) function?  While debugging/optimizing it is convenient to quickly see how a certain function was programmed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `@edit` macro, which is supposed to take you to the definition of a method, similarly to how the `@which` macro which shows the file and line # where that particular method was defined, for example:

```
julia> @which push!(CDFBuf(),"foo")
push!{T<:CDF.CDFBuf}(buff::T, x) at /d/base/DA/DA.jl:105

julia> @which search("foobar","foo")
search(s::AbstractString, t::AbstractString) at strings/search.jl:146
```

Note that methods that are part of Julia will show a path relative to the julia source directory "base".

Comment: Thanks Remy and Scott for your answers.  I guess the @edit macro is the thing I need.  I do get a notice that I use an unknown editor, but I see that it tries to point me to the corresponding file and location nevertheless.  Any recommendations for an editor for Windows 7?

Comment: Back when I still used Windows, I used Epsilon (an Emacs like editor, with C-like extension language), but that unfortunately has no Julia support.  I would imagine that Atom would work on Windows, since it is browser based, and that is what all my colleagues are using (I personally use Gnu Emacs now, on Mac OS X)

Answer (score 3):

While this is not an automatic feature available with Julia in general (as pointed out by Stefan), if you add docstrings when you define your initial function, you can always use the `help?>` prompt to query this docstring. For example

```
julia> """mytestfunction(a::Int, b)""" function mytestfunction(a::Int, b)
    return true
```

This attaches the docstring "mytestfunction(a::Int, b)" to the function `mytestfunction(a::Int, b)`. Once this is defined, you can then use the Julia help prompt (by typing `?` at the REPL), to query this documentation.

```
help?> mytestfunction 
    mytestfunction(a::Int, b)
```